# Length of the arc traveled by a particle with some launch conditions

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, mathematica

I have a 3D particle that is launching with some initial position, velocity, and with a constant force. I can solve for it's position at some time with the following equation:

f
   [
   
    p_
    ,
     
    v_
    ,
     
    t_
    ,
     
    f_
   
   ]
  
   
  =
   
  
   p
    
   +
    
   
    (
    
     v
     *
     t
    
    )
   
    
   +
    
   
    (
    
     f
      
     *
      
     
      (
      
       1
       /
       2
      
      )
     
      
     *
      
     t
      
     *
      
     t
    
    )

My goal is to find the distance the particle travels along the trajectory from time 0 to time "t". To solve this, I've tried splitting up the 3D equation into each dimension, taking the magnitude of that addition, and finding the definite integral. Unfortunately, I got stuck at the integration, and Mathematica wasn't giving me an answer. Is this something that can actually be integrated? I've included a snapshot of my Mathematica notebook below. Is my technique wrong?

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmVID.png)

Comment: It looks like the integrand is the distance to the origin. This will not give you arc length. You need to integrate $\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2+\dot z^2}$.

Comment: Calculate the speed of the particle, sqrt(v_x^2 + v_y^2) and integrate it for the time travelled. It is clearly projectile motion as you can see.